# Cannot uninstall App from iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

Before Xcode 4.5, i could just uninstall my apps like i do on real devices, holding the icon inside springboard and hitting the X, but now it just freezes the simulator and nothing happens.

I know i can go into iphone simulator folder and delete the app from there, but i miss the quick shortcut.

Anyone else having the same issue or know how to fix it?

Im using Mountain Lion and Xcode 4.5.1.

Comment: I am using the same configuration as you, but have no issues deleting by 'holding the icon inside springboard and hitting the X'

Comment: Works perfectly fine for me (Xcode 4.5.1, iOS 6 Simulator, Mountain Lion).

Comment: Can you guys test on iphone simulator 5.1 retina and non-retina? Looks like the 6 and 5 are working fine.

Comment: It's a known issue on the iOS 5.1 simulator. It has a number of known issues. The apple developer forums are the best place for that kind of info and please file a bug report.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on iOS 5.1 simulator - Moutain Lion - XCode 4.5.2

Comment: You can resolve this by deleting the app bundle from your simulator in the command line;

    rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/<SDK version>/<App Bundle>

Comment: Same here. Happens on both Xcode 4.6 and Xcode 5

Comment: Disable: Hardware > Touch Pressure > Use Trackpad Force